# Wütend auf und über

Tags: meaning, difference

Kann man den Unterschied zwischen "wütend auf etwas" und "wütend über etwas" leicht erklären?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normalerweise ist man nicht wütend auf etwas, sondern wütend auf eine Person (oder auch eine Gruppe von Personen):

> Ich bin wütend auf den Autofahrer, der mir die Vorfahrt genommen hat.

"Wütend über" wird dagegen eher in Bezug auf einen Sachverhalt oder einen Vorgang verwendet:

> Ich bin wütend darüber, dass der Autofahrer mir die Vorfahrt genommen hat.

Answer (score 2):

> Ich bin wütend *auf* das QA-Team.

= Ich ärgere mich darüber, wie das Team seine Arbeit macht oder wie sie sich ansonsten verhalten. ("Team" als beseeltes Wesen, das soziale Beziehungen eingehen kann)

> Ich bin wütend *über* das QA-Team.

= Ich ärgere mich darüber, dass es so ein Team gibt. ("Team" als reiner Gegenstand, mit dem kein Gespräch beabsichtigt ist)

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin wütend über den Hund in meinem Garten und auf seinen Besitzer.

Der Hund ist der Grund warum ich wütend bin. Sein Besitzer ist die Person, die ich dafür gerne bestrafen würde.

Auch möglich: Ich bin wütend über die Wühllöcher in meinem Garten und auf den Hund, der sie gegraben hat. Und noch mehr auf seinen Besitzer, der nicht auf seinen Hund aufpasst. Ich würde den Hund gerne für seine Wühlerei bestrafen.